# Typeset bibliography as part of a cls file

Tags: bibliographies

For several papers, the same bibliography files are used and always written at the bottom of the paper:

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{../biba,../bibb,../bibc}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to hide these commands form the user and simply use a .cls file that import the bibliographies with the correct style. This is useful if for instance the number of files can increase and items are moved from one file to another one.

Comment: `\AtEndDocument{\bibliography{<whatever>}}`?

Comment: Indeed, that did the job, can you post this as an answer, I will accept it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it, but surely you know better about your environment.

The trick is

```
\AtEndDocument{\bibliography{<whatever>}}
```

but you should be aware that pending floats could be printed *after* the bibliography.